# Define a simple hash function..

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am so confused by this.. I am not even sure where to start.

Define a simple hash function on strings c = c1c2…cn to be
h(key)= (∑_(i=1)^n〖position in alphabet(c_i)〗)mod 10
where the position in the alphabet is a=1, b=2….

So h(“cat”) = (3 + 1 + 20) mod 10 = 4.

a) If we try to populate the table in the following key order, using linear searching in case of collisions, what will the final table look like? (“hat”, “sat”, “rat”, “cat”, “mat”, “bat”)

b)Suppose we wanted to speed computation by using a hash function that only used the index of the first character in a key, rather than summing all indices in the key.  Would this affect the rate of collisions?  Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Start by generating $h(hat)$. Place it in the position indexed by the hash function. Then try $h(sat)$. Repeat this process. So $h(cat) = 4$ tells you to place "cat" in slot $4$.

b) Suppose I gave you strings ("hat", "home", "heaven", "haven"), how many collisions would you get if you hashed only by the first character? Now compare this to your original hash function.